# Is it possible to search for a boolean in mongo with an ajax post without server side conversion?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb

I have a mongo collection with documents containing a boolean field :

```
{ 
  name : "Tom",
  active : true
}
{
   name : "Jerry",
   active : false
}
```

On the client side of my application I have an element that when clicked fires off an AJAX post that looks for all documents containing either active is equal to true or active is equal to false.

So the ajax post is as follows :

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url : "/dev/search/searchMongo",
                type : "POST",
                data : {
                    JSON.stringify({ active : false })
                },
                success : function(html) {
                    alert(html)
                }
            })
```

The problem is is that the false value in the query is parsed to a string as part of the POST. As far as I know theres nothing I can do about that.

Is it possible to structure the query so that mongo treats the string as a boolean?
I've looked through the docs and found the $type operator that allows you to search based on a values datatype so I thought there might be some way to achieve what I'm looking for. If not I'll throw in some server side conversion logic but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is how you are sending the data and how you are treating it on the receiving end. What you really want to do is post the "body" of the request as JSON and then make sure your server implementation is parsing that JSON body in a way where you have that data available. The default as you are doing is "form encoded".

Your ajax request should look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "/dev/search/searchMongo",
    type : "POST",
    data : JSON.stringify({
      active : false
    }),
    success : function(html) {
        alert(html)
    }
})
```

Then your application end on the server "parses" the body which allows the JSON to come out as an object. Very simple for JavaScript.

On the other end the "body parser" part of your otherwise normal "RESTful" service should translate the JSON "String" to an actual object. This should be the case for other languages other than JavaScript for your server but you might need to look at the parser implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I over simplified the example in my question and left out the JSON.stringify. It doesn't make a difference though as it will still be treated as a string

Comment: @Travis It's about the "body parser". And sorry for accidentally hitting the post answer button while in the middle of typing. But still not finished yet. The downvotes are just from a couple of people you really should not listen to.

Comment: *Slaps head. Whoops. Ignore my last comment, this works as expected. Thanks very much. There was an issue with another field in the query.